# Platform specific with model styling appcelerator

Tags: iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to style my application in appcelerator . In tss file , can I style based on the model of phone .
".clsview"[platform = iphone model=6s] 
Is there any provision for such kind of styling ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the styling in many possible ways.

But first, you should take a look at this link to get familiar with how Alloy Styling works: **[Alloy MVC Theme & Styling](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes)**

Alloy allows to define specific styling based on `true/false` values like this:

```
// alloy.js
Alloy.Globals.iPhone6s = (OS_IOS && Ti.Platform.osname == "iphone" && Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight == 667); 

// Since iPhone5s screen size is 640x1136, you can check for platformHeight == 568 as its DP is 2
Alloy.Globals.iPhone5s = (OS_IOS && Ti.Platform.osname == "iphone" && Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight == 568);  


// in tss
".clsview"[if=Alloy.Globals.iPhone6s] 

".iphone5s"[if=Alloy.Globals.iPhone5s] : {
    backgroundColor : 'cyan'
}

// to apply class only on tablets, use 'formFactor = handheld/tablet'
'.tablet'[formFactor=tablet]:{color:'blue'}
'.phones'[formFactor=handheld]:{color:'red'}

// to use multiple 'if' statements inside tss, you can combine them inside alloy.js
```

Comment: I want to create Alloy.Globals.iPhone5s . What conditions should I put ?